# matlab How to remove .jpg from file name

Tags: matlab, filenames

I am looping through a lot of files and I need to remove the '.jpg' from each name.

Example file name:

```
20403y.jpg
```

but I just need the

```
20403y
```

All the file names end with 'y' if that helps.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean... do you have the names stored in a variable in matlab and wish to remove ".jpg", or do you want to batch rename files?

Comment: Yes, I have a variable with the file name and I want to remove the .jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is with regular expressions:

```
filename = 'myfilename.jpg';
pattern = '.jpg';
replacement = '';
regexprep(filename,pattern,replacement)
```

Result:

```
ans =

myfilename
```

If you have the filenames in a cell array feed the cell array to `regexprep`. As the documentation explains, "If str is a cell array of strings, then the regexprep return value s is always a cell array of strings having the same dimensions as str."

Example:

```
myfilenames = {'myfilename.jpg' 'afilename.jpg' 'anotherfilename.jpg' };
newfilenames= regexprep(myfilenames,'.jpg','');
```

Result:

```
newfilenames = 

    'myfilename'    'afilename'    'anotherfilename'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
files = dir('*y.jpg');

% Loop through each
for id = 1:length(files)
    % Get the file name (minus the extension)
    [p, f] = fileparts(files(id).name); % f will just give you file name

    % Use following to rename the files
    % I think you don't want to rename them
    % movefile(files(id).name, f);  
end
```

Comment: In this case I think `regexp` and `strrep` are preferable, as they can operate on cell arrays...